# realtime database rules wildcard

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

as soon as I use a wildcard I get this error:
Unhandled Exception: [firebase_database/permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

works:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "user": {
        ".write": "auth != null",
        ".read": "auth != null"
    }
}
```

doesn't work:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "user": {
      "$userId": {
        ".write": "auth != null && $userId === auth.uid",
        ".read": "auth != null"
      }
    }
}
```

doesn't work:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "user": {
      "$userId": {
        ".write": true,
        ".read": true
      }
    }
}
```

db structure:

[image]

code:

```
List<User>? userlist;
late Query query;
 
 void initState() {
    userAuth.FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((userAuth.User? user)  {

      final FirebaseApp abcApp = Firebase.app();
      final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instanceFor(app: abcApp);
      userlist = [];
      query = database
          .ref().child("user").orderByChild("userId")
          .equalTo(
          ownUid==true
              ?user!.uid
              :widget.peerId
      );
      _onOrderAddedSubscription1 = query.onChildAdded.listen(onEntryAdded1);
      _onOrderChangedSubscription1 = query.onChildChanged.listen(onEntryChanged1);
    });   
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Security rules on themselves don't do anything yet. Can you edit your question to show the [minimal code that we can all run against these rules to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're trying to read from `/users`. If you do that with the second set of rules, it gets rejected as those rules don't grant anyone permission to read all of `/users` - but only allows one to read `/users/$uid`.

It helps to recall that security rules on their own [don't filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#rules-not-filters), but instead merely check whether all data access is authorized.

So if you want to allow reading from `/users`, you need a rule on `/users` that allows that read. And if you want to allow reading specific data under `/users`, you either need to read from that specific path or [combine a query and rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules) so that the rules can verify that the client is only reading data they're authorized for.

This problem comes up quite regularly, so I also recommend checking out more [questions about 'rules are not filters'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+rules+are+not+filters)

Comment: I want every user to only be able to write their own data and read everyone as long as they authenticate. The users are directly under /user. Every user has 3 subfolders, maybe thats a problem?

Comment: The problem is more likely to be what I answered already, but it's hard to be certain until we can see the minimal code that gives the problem, as I asked in my comment to your question.

Comment: @Fank van Puffelen, I added the code, i thought the code doesn't matter ...sorry

Comment: The code shows you're trying to read `/users`, which your rules don't give access to. It is quite literally the scenario I wrote in my answer, so I recommend taking some more time to read that and all the links in it. If you want to make the rules work for the code, you'll need to write a rule on `/users` that validated the query, as shown in this link that I also shared in my answer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules